# Encrypt with crypto-js, decrypt in crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a string with crypto-js and decrypting it using crypto (AES 256 CBC). However if, e.g. the message is "* test message to be encrypted *" I get an output where the second half is fine, but the first has junk like "���~t_�d}~a'/o be encrypted *". If I decrypt using crypto-js it is fine.

This is the code I use to encrypt:

```
let CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
let ENC_KEY = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQ";
let IV = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQ";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    "* test message to be encrypted *",
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(ENC_KEY),
    {
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(IV),
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    }
);

console.log(encrypted);
```

This is the code to decrypt:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
var messageToDecrypt = Buffer.from(message, "base64");
var key = Buffer.from(ENC_KEY, "utf8");
var iv = Buffer.from(IV, "utf8");
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
var clearText = decipher.update(messageToDecrypt, 'base64', 'utf-8');
clearText += decipher.final("utf-8");

console.log(clearText);
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the issue?

Comment: The first 16 characters of the decrypt output are not correct, but the rest is fine. May it be related to padding managed differently in the 2 libs?

Comment: The IV is parsed with the Hex encoder in the current CryptoJS code, which is wrong. Instead it must be parsed with the Utf8 encoder (analogous to the key).